# NSFontAttributeName has changed to String

Tags: string, swift, uinavigationbar

i'm trying to style the navigation bar properly, i need to change the font to helvetica neue with a size point of 19. I've ever used this code but i've notice that now doesn't work as well:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19)]
```

this happens because the type of NSFontAttributeName has changed to String, i've tried to fix it with

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: "HelveticaNeue-Light, 19"]
```

but the compiler continue to give me an error related to point size in font, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The `UIFont` constructor is returning an optional (`UIFont?`) which you must unwrap to use.  Add `!` if you're sure you have a valid font name:

**Swift 4.2:**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19)!]
```

**Swift 4:**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19)!]
```

**Swift 3:**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19)!]
```

**Note:** If you are setting a font with a static name in your code, then force unwrapping is safe once you’ve verified you’re using a valid font name. If you are getting the font name from an external source (the user or a server), you will want to use *optional binding* such as `if let font = UIFont(...` or `guard let font = UIFont(...` to safely unwrap the font before use.

Answer (score 50):

With **Swift 4** NSFontAttributeName is deprecated, you can use NSAttributedStringKey values to set attributes.

```
if let fontStyle = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19) {
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontStyle]
}
```

With **Swift 4.2** `NSAttributedStringKey` is changed as `NSAttributedString.Key`.

```
if let fontStyle = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19) {
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: fontStyle]
}
```

For more options for NSAttributedStringKey you can visit this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

NSAttributedStringKey has renamed to NSAttributedString.Key in Swift 4.2

```
if let fontStyle = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19) {
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: fontStyle]
}
```